# How to set Backend in Varnish Cache for a remote Shared hosting?

Tags: apache, varnish, varnish-vcl

I want to use my server (where it's installed Varnished) to cache webpage of a remote web hosting

**Default.vcl**

```
backend default {
    .host = "shavrea.com";
    .port = "80";
}
```

If a write this, doesn't work and **return me** this error:

```
Site Temporarily Unavailable

We apologize for the inconvenience. Please contact the webmaster/ tech support immediately to have them rectify this.
error id: "bad_httpd_conf"
```

This is because that backend is on a shared server. How to resolve this?

Comment: So, your Varnish is on a different server to your Apache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to explicitly set the Host header.

```
sub vcl_recv {
  set req.http.host = "shavrea.com";
}
```