# Set up Varnish with heroku app - what backend host and port do i use?

Tags: heroku, varnish

I'm trying to set up a Varnish server with my Heroku app. I'm having difficulties setting up the backend host and port to point to my heroku app.

I tried entering it like this:

```
backend default {
    .host = "gavedrysset-api.herokuapp.com";
    .port = "80";
}
```

This does not work and is giving me an heroku error page saying this:

```
Heroku | No such app

There is no app configured at that hostname.
Perhaps the app owner has renamed it, or you mistyped the URL.
```

How can i make varnish point to my heroku app?

Comment: you're probably not passing a required host header or some such. anyhow, why would you do this?

Comment: I'm getting a feeling i have misunderstood something very basic here. I want to use varnish to cache static content from my heroku app, and i thought i had to set my heroku app as the "backend default" to accomplish this?

Comment: where is that backend default config going? where's your varnish server?

Comment: generally I'd say just put static contents in a cdn or use something like cloudflare.

Comment: The varnish server is on a vps, located in europe. I would gladly use a cdn, but in this case i'm just doing this because i want to learn about varnish. I thought i could try varnish with one of my heroku apps for learning purposes.

Comment: my impression from the error message is that heroku is not seeing the original intended host, ie. gavedrysset-api.herokuapp.com, so it doesn't know how to route to your app. You're probably losing that information at some point in varnish.

Comment: seems that way. If i ping my app and use the ip as url in the browser i get the same error. I think i might have to use something like this: https://addons.heroku.com/proximo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution. I have no idea what i am doing though...
Found the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240148/how-to-set-backend-in-varnish-cache-for-a-remote-shared-hosting?rq=1) thread.

I added this to default.vcl:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    set req.http.host = "gavedrysset-api.herokuapp.com";
}
```